# Nesting IFs in Excel to evaluate a condition and then applying a formula

Tags: excel

I have a formula that evaluates if a cell is blank or has 'N/A' in it and then applies different weights to six different cells based on the finding and does some multiplication (the formula below works fine).  How do I first check a cell (say B2) so that I can apply a different formula based on B2?  So if B2 is 'Dog' I am going to run the formula below but I'll change the reference rows, so if B2 is 'Dog' I'll reference Row 729 in my formula and if it's 'Cat' I'll reference Row 730 in my formula.  Let's say I have 3 different potential values for B2.  Thanks!

=IF(OR(AD2="N/A",AD2=0),0,AD2*AD$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AE2="N/A",AE2=0),0,AE2*AE$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AF2="N/A",AF2=0),0,AF2*AF$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AG2="N/A",AG2=0),0,AG2*AG$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AH2="N/A",AH2=0),0,AH2*AH$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))+IF(OR(AI2="N/A",AI2=0),0,AI2*AI$729/(AD$729*AND(AD2<>0,AD2<>"N/A")+AE$729*AND(AE2<>0,AE2<>"N/A")+AF$729*AND(AF2<>0,AF2<>"N/A")+AG$729*AND(AG2<>0,AG2<>"N/A")+AH$729*AND(AH2<>0,AH2<>"N/A")+AI$729*AND(AI2<>0,AI2<>"N/A")))

[image: criti]

Comment: Post few sample data then desired output.

Comment: You could use a VLOOKUP to get different reference values for 'Dog', 'Cat' etc. Nested IF can be replaced with IFS which is easier to read. See if [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8) helps.